# Arbitrarily change axis properties in pgfplots within a foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, axis

I have a bunch of plots which I want to insert as subfigures within a larger figure. Because they share the same y-axes, I don't want to waste space repeating the same axis and tick labels for each plot, so would like to only put the labels on the leftmost plot in each row (the number of plots in each row can be arbitrary), and also add legends on the rightmost plots in each row (in different positions)

A MWE is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\def\plotlist{3/2,2/3,-4/-2,-2/-4,-3/-4}
\def\fplotwidth{0.33}
\def\plotsepdist{-0.8cm}
\def\plotlinebreak{2}

\foreach \i/\j [count=\plotcount] in \plotlist{
    \subfloat[$f_1: \i{}x^2$, $f_2: \j{}x^2$]{
        \adjustbox{max width=\fplotwidth\linewidth}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=xlabel text,
                     xlabel near ticks,
                     yticklabels={,,},
                     ymin=-10,
                     ymax=10,
                     xmin=-2,
                     xmax=2]
        
        % \ifthenelse{\plotcount=1 \or \plotcount=3}{INSERT Y TICK LABELS AND Y AXIS LABEL (near yticks)}
        % \ifthenelse{\plotcount=2}{\legend{$f_1$,$f_2$} (in bottom right}{}
        % \ifthenelse{\plotcount=5}{\legend{$f_1$,$f_2$} (in top right}{}
        
        \addplot[blue] {\i*x^2};
        \addplot[red] {\j*x^2};
        % Plot code
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
\ifthenelse{\plotcount=\plotlinebreak}{\\}{\hspace{\plotsepdist}}
}
\caption{The main caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

producing:

[image]

I would like to add `ylabel=ylabel text` and `ylabel near ticks` to the axis properties, and also switch `yticklabels` back on for (in this case) `\plotcount=1` and `\plotcount=3`. Additionally, I would like to add `\legend{$f_1$,$f_2$}` when `\plotcount=2` and `\plotcount=5`, and position it in the bottom right for plot 2 and top right for plot 5. Is there a way to change axis properties, after they have already been set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\pgfplotsset` inside the `axis` environment to add certain options to the already existing options.

If you set the y ticks only to some plots, the scaling of the plots will be different. Therefore I added a line of code that sets the bounding box.

So, you could go like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\def\plotlist{3/2,2/3,-4/-2,-2/-4,-3/-4}
\def\fplotwidth{0.33}
\def\plotsepdist{-0.8cm}
\def\plotlinebreak{2}

\foreach \i/\j [count=\plotcount] in \plotlist{
    \subfloat[$f_1: \i{}x^2$, $f_2: \j{}x^2$]{
        \adjustbox{max width=\fplotwidth\linewidth}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[xlabel near ticks,
                     ylabel near ticks,
                     ymin=-10,
                     ymax=10,
                     xmin=-2,
                     xmax=2,
                     legend pos=north east]
        
        \ifthenelse{\not \plotcount=1 \and \not \plotcount=3}{
            \pgfplotsset{yticklabels={,,}}
        }{}
        \ifthenelse{\plotcount=2}{
            \pgfplotsset{legend pos=south east}
            \legend{$f_1$,$f_2$}
        }{}
        \ifthenelse{\plotcount=5}{
            \legend{$f_1$,$f_2$}
        }{}
        
        \addplot[blue] {\i*x^2};
        \addplot[red] {\j*x^2};
        % Plot code
        \end{axis}
        
        \pgfresetboundingbox
        \path ([shift={(-10pt,-10pt)}]current axis.south west)
        rectangle ([shift={(10pt,10pt)}]current axis.north east);
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
\ifthenelse{\plotcount=\plotlinebreak}{\\}{\hspace{\plotsepdist}}
}
\caption{The main caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your help! I didn't know about the bounding box, that makes my life a lot easier as I was just doing trial and error with an adjustbox, haha